# meaning of 'over the weekend'

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms

*Did you see your mom over the weekend?*

Would 'over' imply more than one day, maybe the whole weekend, or would it just mean at some point during the weekend?

Comment: 'Over' the weekend means 'during the weekend'. The question is asking if the listener saw their mother at least once during the weekend. It does not mean 'for the whole weekend'.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of *over the weekend* is contextually dependent. The meaning of *over the weekend* will will change with your intended meaning and your audience's current understanding of the situation.

*Did you **see** you mom over the weekend,* can mean for five minutes, one day, or the whole weekend.  *See* as you have used means *visit* and a visit can last five minutes, a whole day, or several days.

If you knew that I was planning to spend Saturday and Sunday with my mom, your question would be asking if I spent both days with her.  If you knew I was planning on a brief visit on Sunday, your question would ask that.  If visiting my mother was something I *might* do over the weekend, your question is asking me if I spent *any* time with her, as well as prompting me for more details of my visit.

If you told me, without context, that *Renee **stayed** with her mom over the weekend* I would not have a clear understanding of which days you meant. In that case *over the weekend* is left undefined.  You say it and I never care or need to know if you mean one day or two.  All you are saying is Renee was there for some amount of time.  We may never actually get to the details because they are contextually unimportant.

If you want to me to know that Renee stayed for both days and you don't want it to be contextually dependent you would use *for* instead of *over*.  *Renee stayed with her mom **for** the weekend.*